# Separating interfaces and Constructor injection

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, architecture

Right now I have a kind of dilemma. There is a class structure that is similar to the following one:

```
public interface IMammal
{
    void Eat();
}

public interface IBarking
{
    void Bark();
}
```

There are instances of `IBarking` and `IMammal`. Theoretically our animal can be either of them or just one. `Cow` is as you can see `IMammal`, and `Dog` is `IMammal` and `IBarking`. In theory we could even have someone who can bark, but isn't a mammal.

```
public class Mammal : IMammal
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        Console.Write("Om-nom-nom");
    }
}

public class Cow : Mammal
{
}

public class Dog : Mammal, IBarking
{
    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.Write("Bark-bark!!!");
    }
}
```

Here is a `Farm`, where only one animal lives:

```
public class Farm
{
    private readonly IMammal _animal;

    public Farm(IMammal animal)
    {
        _animal = animal;
    }

    public void Feed()
    {
        _animal.Eat();
    }

    public void Guard()
    {
        var dog = _animal as IBarking;
        if (dog != null)
            dog.Bark();
    }
}
```

The problem, I can see here, is that we assume that `IBarking` is always `IMammal`. What is wrong with this design, how could it be fixed?

Comment: You are assuming that `Dog` is always `IMammal`, which it is, although the `IMammal` may not be a `Dog`. I'm not sure where you are seeing that `IBarking` is assumed to be a `IMammal` in the code? You are picking a concrete type, you could have done something like `var barker = _animal as IBarking` which would make your question make sense... But even that doesn't assume `IBarking` is a mammal, only that the mammal *might* implement it.

Comment: @RonBeyer Sorry. It is my mistake. I've corrected the code so that now I cast to `IBarking`. The situation is that I can't provide any other kind of `IBarking` except for those, who implement `IMammal`.

Comment: Your implementation, by the way its written, can only take `IMammals` and Guard will only do `IBarking` so by design it can only accept barking mammals if `Guard` is to do anything. If you want it to accept all `IBarking` regardless of them being mammals, then you need to use `IBarking` in the constructor, and do the same check in `Feed`. Maybe you need to make a higher up interface, like `IAlive` or `IFauna` that can encapsulate both mammals and barking "things" (assuming barking things are alive).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such simplified examples hardly make any sense. You're missing the "problem case" and what you want to do then. Show a class that implements `IBarking` but not `IMammal` and what problems arise when you pass it to `Farm`. Anyway, given the premises:

- Interface `IMammal` exists.
- Interface `IBarking` exists.
- A class implementing `IBarking` does not *have* to implement `IMammal`.
- Class constructor `Farm` has to accept `IBarking` *and* `IMammal`.
- Current class constructor accepts `IMammal`.

In this case you either need a new constructor, a new private member and more code to choose between the two, or an overlapping interface. I'd go with the latter: `IFarmable`.

Then you need:

- `public interface IMammal : IFarmable`
- `public interface IBarking : IFarmable`
- `public Farm(IFarmable farmable) { ... }`

Most likely you have other constraints, like *"but I want to call `Eat()` on the variable passed into the constructor"*, but then your description (*"we assume that `IBarking` is always `IMammal`"*) is incorrect or incomplete and you need to move `Eat()` to the `IFarmable` interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to interpret your ***intention***.

1. You want to have a farm where animals grow up (to later be slaughtered for food).
2. You might need another animal guarding them (might since you tried the cast).

A better design for that would be:

```
public class Farm
{
    private readonly IMammal[] _animals;

    public Farm(IMammal[] animals)
    {
        _animals = animals;
    }

    public void Feed()
    {
       foreach (var animal in _animals)
            animal.Eat();
    }

    public IBarking GuardingAnimal { get; set; }

    public void Guard()
    {
        if (GuardingAnimal != null)
            GuardingAnimal .Bark();
    }
}
```

Changes from your design:

1. I've made it crystal clear that there can be a guarding animal
2. The guarding animal is optional (as it's assign through a property instead of the constructor).

The reason that I wanted to make that distinction is that most animals are passive (you feed and harvest them) while the guard animal has a specific use case and should therefor not be hidden among the others.

If you want to feed the dog you, you should make that interface inherit `IMammal` (unless you introduce more functionality in mammal in which case you should extract `IFeedable` or similar).

Comment: The point is not to implement an ideal farm. It is just an example. The problem is that right now I have a similar piece of code and it feels a bit smelly to me. I can't decide if I should redactor it, and if yes then how.